# Is this Matrix Orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

The matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\ 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{14}} & \frac{2}{\sqrt{14}} &\frac{-3}{\sqrt{14}} \\ 
 \frac{-5}{\sqrt{42}}& \frac{4}{\sqrt{42}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{42}}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Its pretty clear that $$A A^T=I$$ But $$A^T A \ne I$$

is it Orthogonal? I know it is not, but i was shocked by the answer given by Marc Van Leeuwen in this link

[There is a $3\times 3 $ orthogonal matrix with all non zero entries.?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279397/there-is-a-3-times-3-orthogonal-matrix-with-all-non-zero-entries)

I was puzzled with this:

we have $$A A^T=I$$ with the given matrix and also $Det(A)=1$ so $A$ is invertible, so pre multiplying with $A^{-1}$ we get

$$A^{-1}A A^T=A^{-1}$$  that is

$$A^T=A^{-1}$$ and now post multiply with $A$ we get

$$A^TA=I$$ which is not satisfied by the given matrix...i donno whats going wrong here?

Comment: Are the column vectors pairwise orthonormal?

Comment: $A^T A \neq I$ , this implies that the colums don't form an othogonal basis. So the matrix is not othogonal.

Comment: $A^T T$ **is** $I$

Comment: What, $AA^T\not=I$?

Comment: yeah i too thought same , but i was confused with the post made by  Marc Van Leeuwen in this link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279397/there-is-a-3-times-3-orthogonal-matrix-with-all-non-zero-entries

Comment: I donno why people downvote just like that...its very bad on their part

Comment: The equality $A^TA=I$ is satisfied by your matrix, please double check your calculations

Comment: Although $A^TA=I$ is less obvious than $AA^T=I$ (the latter seems more or less by design), it is no less true.

Comment: yes sir i got it thanks

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are square matrices then $AB = I$ if and only if $BA = I$. To see this, suppose $AB = I$. Then $B$ has a left inverse (is injective) hence a right inverse (is surjective). So there is some matrix $C$ such that $BC = I$ but then $A = A(BC) = (AB)C = C$. So $BA = I$.

Answer (score 1):

$A$  is orthogonal if and only if $a.b = 0$ and $a.a = 1$ where a, b are any row of $A$. and $a.b = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_ib_i)$

Now check whether your Matrix's rows satisfy  this condition or not.

Comment: rows satisfy but columns?

Comment: then it suffices... @EkaveeraKumarSharma