# memorable 3D unit vectors with distinct components

Tags: vectors

This question may be rather trivial, but I haven't been able to find any source dealing with it for some reason, so I figured I might as well ask about it:

I am looking for a memorable example of a 3D vector of unit length and with all three components being non-zero and different from one another. Ideally, the vector components should be rational numbers that one can easily keep in mind and write down in decimal form (i.e. with a finite decimal representation like $0.625$ instead of $\frac{1}{3}$).

Also interesting would be vectors whose components can all be expressed as some kind of logical series (like e.g. $(0.225, 0.425, 0.625)$ or $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{3}{\sqrt{3}})$). In this case I'd be less strict about the finite decimal representation, if the expressions are still rather short and memorable.

Finally, are there any general "construction" rules by which you can arrive at several such vectors easily?

Comment: One example: $(1/\sqrt{13},2/\sqrt{13},3/\sqrt{13})$.

Comment: $(0.48, 0.6, 0.64)$

Comment: Another example: $(\sqrt{1/6},\sqrt{2/6},\sqrt{3/6})$, which you could simplify to $(1/\sqrt{6},1/\sqrt{3},1/\sqrt{2})$. It doesn't satisfy the condition of rationality, but is still fairly memorable.

Comment: @parcly-taxel shouldn't it be $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{14}}, \frac{2}{\sqrt{14}}, \frac{3}{\sqrt{14}})$ in that example? (1+4+9=14)

Comment: @Sty Yes, sorry. Any three different squares added together can serve as a basis.

Comment: See this question about orthogonal $3\times3$ matrices with rational entries:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279397/there-is-a-3-times-3-orthogonal-matrix-with-all-non-zero-entries