# How to generate problems on QR factorization?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to come up with a generator for the QR factorization type of problems for $3 \times 3$ matrices. The main idea of my generator is to have neat numbers along the task.

I wanted to create matrix $Q$ using rotation matrices and identity matrix, but it doesn't seem to give more or less acceptable values.

Maybe I should approach this problem differently if it is possible at all?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/279426/62839) for $Q$.

Comment: @user1337 that actually solves my whole problem. Thank you a lot!